Algorithm for fixed point in provability logic
I am studying Boolos' The Logic of Provability and cannot follow  the procedure on p. 110. It gives an algorithm for finding fixed points in "modalized p-sentences" (sentences where the variable p only appears within the scope of a box).
But how to get the fixed point of, for example
$$\Box(\Box p\rightarrow\neg\Box\neg p)$$
Or is this not a modalized p-sentence in the sense of the algorithm?
Is there a better worked out description of the algorithm?
Also with thinking about letterless sentences, I was thinking if p is a letterless sentence, then
Is $\mathbf{GL}\vdash\Box p\vee\Box\neg p$ a theorem?

Here's a MathJax tutorial :)

I shall describe a merely practical way to trace the algorithm; an annotated examination that gives its theoretical basis and justification would need a text of considerable length by itself. In this connection, I strongly recommend a thorough study of the chapter "Modal Logic and Provability" of the book Computability and Logic by Boolos et al. which I, too, shall freely make some use of in the following as well as the book referred to. So,

A modal sentence is said to be a tautology if it can be obtained
from a valid sentence of nonmodal sentential logic by substituting
modal sentences for sentence letters. Thus, since $p\vee\neg p$ is
valid for any sentence letter $p$, $A\vee\neg A$ is a tautology for
any modal sentence $A$.

Hence, $\Box p\vee\Box\neg p$ is a theorem of $\mathbf{GL}$.

A sentence $H$ is a fixed point of $A$ (with respect to $p$) if $H$
contains only sentence letters contained in $A$, $H$ does not contain
$p$, and

$$\mathbf{GL}\vdash\boxdot(p\leftrightarrow A)\rightarrow(p\leftrightarrow H)$$
For any $A$,
$\boxdot A\leftrightarrow A\wedge\Box A$;
$\Box^{0} A = A$ and $\Box^{n}$ denotes nested $n$ boxes.
$H$, A letterless sentence (i.e., a sentence whose symbols are among only $\Box, \top, \bot$, apart from propositional connectives), is in normal form if it is a truth-functional compound of sentences $\Box^{n}\bot$.
Then,

If $A$ is a $p$-sentence modalised in $p$, then there exists a
letterless sentence $H$ in normal form that is a fixed point for $A$
relative to $p$.

$A$ is
$$\Box p\rightarrow\Box\neg p$$
To go further, the rank of a world on a finite, transitive and irreflexive frame $\langle W, R\rangle$ has to be noted, which is crucial for the reasoning of the algorithm:
A sequence of worlds can be formed such that $w_{n}Rw_{n-1}\ldots w_{1}Rw_{0}$ for some $w\ldots w_{1}, w_{0}\in W$. We notice that if $j > i$, $w_{j}Rw_{i}$ by transitivity, and $w_{i}\neq w_{j}$ by irreflexivity. Thus for every $w\in W$, there is a greatest $n$, which will be less than the number of members of $W$ such that  $w = w_{n}Rw_{n-1}\ldots w_{1}Rw_{0}$. For each $w\in W$, the rank of $w$ as the greatest such $n$. The ranks of worlds will correspond to the rows of the table we aim to set up according to the specifications below:
At rank $0$,

The boxed formulas get vacuously $\top$.
$p$ gets the same assignment as $A$; hence, $\top$. Therefore, $\neg p$ gets $\bot$.
"Truth-functional compounds inherit their truth-values on a row from those of their components as usual (thus $\bot$ gets $\bot$ on every row)."

At rank $1$:

Set $\Box p$ to $\top$ since $p$ has got $\top$ on all the previous rows and so for all the sentences with the same relation of form (viz., $\Box D$ to $D$).

Likewise, for the ranks 2 and 3. Thus, we obtain the table (the columns on the left are for the components of $A$ and those on the right are for $H$):
\begin{array} {c | c c c c c | c c}
 & \Box p & \Box\neg p & \Box p\rightarrow\Box\neg p & p & \neg p & \bot & \Box\bot & \Box\Box\bot \\
 \hline  0 & \top & \top & \top & \top & \bot & \bot & \top & \top \\
 1 & \top & \bot & \bot & \bot & \top & \bot & \bot & \top \\
 2 & \bot & \bot & \top & \top & \bot & \bot & \bot & \bot \\
 3 & \bot & \bot & \top & \top & \bot & \bot & \bot & \bot \\
\end{array}
We observe that the row of rank 3 repeats the previous row, hence the series of steps has stabilised at rank 2 and there is no need to carry on.
We shall calculate $H$ according to the following conditions:
(1) On the row $A$ gets $\top$, $H$ is the conjunction of $\Box^{j}\bot\neg\vee\Box^{j+1}\bot$ where $j$ denotes the previous rows on which $A$ gets $\bot$.
(2) On the row $A$ gets $\bot$, $H$ is the disjunction of $\neg(\Box^{j}\bot\vee\neg\Box^{j+1}\bot)$ where $j$ denotes the previous rows on which $A$ gets $\top$.
On the row of rank 2, $A$ stands as $\top$, so we shall apply (1). $A$ stands as $\bot$ only at row 1, therefore $H$ is
$$\Box\bot\vee\neg\Box^{2}\bot$$
alternatively,
$$\Box\Box\bot\rightarrow\Box\bot$$
We can similarly work out the sentence $\Box(\Box p\rightarrow\neg\Box\neg p)$ in the question, noticing that it is of the form $\Box D$ and see that its fixed point in normal form is $\neg H$.
